# Solr delta import on changes in entity within a document

Tags: solr, import, delta

I have the following data-config:

```
<document name="locations">
    <entity pk="id" name="location" query="select * from locations WHERE isapproved='true'" 
            deltaImportQuery="select * from locations WHERE updatedate &lt; getdate() AND isapproved='true' AND id='${dataimporter.delta.id}'" 
            deltaQuery="select id from locations where isapproved='true' AND updatedate &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">

            <!-- more document fields -->

    </entity>
    <entity pk="id" name="offerdetails" query="SELECT title AS offer_title,ISNULL(img,'') AS offer_thumb,id AS offer_id
    ,startdate AS offer_startdate
    ,enddate AS offer_enddate
    ,description AS offer_description
    FROM offers WHERE objectid=${location.id} AND objecttype=${location.objecttype} AND approved='true' AND startdate &lt; getdate() AND enddate &gt; getdate()"
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT title AS offer_title,ISNULL(img,'') AS offer_thumb,id AS offer_id
    ,startdate AS offer_startdate
    ,enddate AS offer_enddate
    ,description AS offer_description FROM offers WHERE updatedate &lt; getdate() AND approved='true' AND id='${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
    deltaQuery="SELECT id FROM offers where approved='true' AND updatedate &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"> 
        <field name="id" column="offer_id" />
        <field name="offer_title" column="offer_title" />
        <field name="offer_thumb" column="offer_thumb" />
        <field name="offer_startdate" column="offer_startdate" />
        <field name="offer_enddate" column="offer_enddate" />
        <field name="offer_description" column="offer_description" />
    </entity>                                
    </document>
```

Now, when the object in the `[locations]` table is updated, my delta import query `/dataimport?command=delta-import` works perfectly. 
But when an offer is updated in the `[offers]` table, this is not seen by the deltaimport command.
Is there way to delta-import only the updated offers for the respective location if an offer is updated?

And then without:
a. having to fully import ALL locations
or
b. having to update this single location and then do a regular deltaimport?

Answer (score 0):

You tried with nested entity, so it works for only with location table because the delta query update is only based on location date update.
Now you have to write delta query for offers and treat this as separate entity.

Example:

```
<entity pk="id" name="location" ....
  deltaImportQuery="select * ..
  deltaQuery="select ....
</entity>

<entity pk="id" name="offers" ....
  deltaImportQuery="select * ..
  deltaQuery="select ....
</entity>
```

Comment: Ok, I updated my `data-config.xml` per your suggestion...but it still doesn't work...why?